# How to clear content div and reappear with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery [CustomBox](http://dixso.github.io/custombox/) modal.  I have it all working fine but I want the div behind it (BUT NOT THE BACKGROUND IMAGE) to disappear when modal is clicked.  I have managed that, but not too sure on the code to make it reappear again after the modal is closed.  At the moment I have to refresh the page in order for it to come back.

Here is the code I am using so far: http://codepen.io/doolz77/pen/esoHB/

I have not included the modal due to the amount of extra code, however, here is a link to the actual [page](http://akboheim.com/tsc/motivation.php)

to make the modal appear just click on the 'joey' link.

Thanks!

EDIT: At the moment it is controlled by jQuery.  The call which is placed in the footer is:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fadein').on('click', function () {
    $.fn.custombox( this {
    effect: 'fadein'
    });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This fades the modal in and out.  Would I just need to place some code here for the #wholePageContainer div to re-appear??

Comment: When do you want it to reappear??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar - I just edited my question as realised I was being quite vague :)  After the modal is closed again either on screen click or using the 'close modal' link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the html before deleting it to retrieve later. Or you can use show/hide To reduce the pain and achieve desired functionality:

```
function clearBox(wholePageContainer)
{
 document.getElementById(wholePageContainer).style.display = "none";
}
function showbox(wholePageContainer)
{
 document.getElementById(wholePageContainer).style.display = "block";
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zncJk/)**

Comment: I just added a link to the actual page in my question.  Will check the Demo out too.  Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you were looking for:

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/giFEL
```

Edited:
Explanation to the above link:
In the above link i have made the html and body tag as 100% and the div element who's content is been removed to some percentage i.e 50%, This will keep the div occupy space event if it is empty.

Next i am storing the html content to a hidden div element and restoring it back to the div when required.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @benka - I have added the link to the actual page in my question.

Comment: @hirenhcm - am I supposed to encase #wholePageContainer within #html?